# Files in "assets" folder are not read-only in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing an Android application where I provide a SQLite database file along with APK in the "assets" folder of the application.  Now they say that, asset files are read only but in my case i could modify it during runtime like changing values of few columns. Is changing value is ignored for read-only database files?

```
void update()
{
    sqLiteDatabase = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE quotes SET likes = '"+ 1 + "' WHERE id ="+count);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE quotes SET dislikes = '"+ 1 + "' WHERE id ="+count);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE quotes SET like_status = '"+ 1 + "' WHERE id ="+count);
}


public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "local_database.db";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "post";
    private static final String COLUMN_1 = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_2 = "content";
    private static final String COLUMN_3 = "likes";
    private static final String COLUMN_4 = "dislikes";
    private static final String COLUMN_5 = "like_status";

    DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int old_version, int new_version) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }

    int get_count()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME, null);
        Integer count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        return count;
    }

    Cursor get_like_status(Integer ID)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = '" + ID + "';", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor;
    }

    Cursor read_data(Integer ID)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = '" + ID + "';", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor;
    }

    boolean update_counts(Integer count, Long likes, Long dislikes) {

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_3, likes);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_4, dislikes);

        return sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "id = " + count, null) != -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you changed the values, as I believe that you only think that you are changing the values as it may appear to work.

Comment: @MikeT - Please check the question now!

Comment: @MikeT - When I call the update method, the values of "likes" and "dislikes" is set to '1' which was previously '0'.

Comment: @mikeT - I am sorry for being stupid newbie and wasting your time. Thank you for your previous answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

The library that you are using (I assume that's [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper%20android-sqlite-asset-helper)) *copies* the database from your asset folder, as indicated in [the documentation](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper%20android-sqlite-asset-helper):

> The database will be extracted from the assets and copied into place within your application's private data directory.

Comment: Hey @njzk2 thank you, you made it clear to me.